# Why does Symfony DI container multiplies instances of a service when API tests are run?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, phpunit, codeception

I have a service that should have only one instance and I was sure that DI container takes care about it. And when I send a request by Postman everything works properly, container returns always the very same instance. I have even added an additional field with a random number generated during object creation for debugging.

```php
class ReadModel
{
    private ?Database $database;

    // Temporary field for debugging purpose
    private int $tmp;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->database = null;

        $this->tmp = rand(1, 1000);
    }

    public function setDatabase(Database $database): void
    {
        $this->database = $database;

        dump($this->tmp); // returns e.g. 836 when codeception test is run
    }

    public function getCollection(string $collectionName): Collection
    {
        dump($this->tmp); // returns e.g. 390 when codeception test is run

        return $this->database->selectCollection($collectionName);
    }
}
```

When a request is sent by Postman (dev environment) both numbers returned by `dump()` function are equal (the same instance is injected to other services that uses it). But when I run a Codeception test, this service behaves differently. When I call `setDatabase()` method of `ReadModel` in one service and `getCollection` methond in another one, I receive two different values of `$tmp` field. That means that two different instances of `ReadModel` service have been injected to my services. How is it possible and what can I do to have the same behavior in both environments (dev and test)?

`ReadModel` service is autowired so I don't paste `services.yaml` content.

My stack: Symfony 5.1, Codeception 4.1

PS. By Codeception tests I mean end2end API tests like this one, not unit tests:

```php
<?php

use Codeception\Util\HttpCode;

class CreateProductCest
{
    public function _before(ApiTester $I)
    {
        // Authentication stuff...
    }

    public function shouldCreateProductWithNoException(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $data = [
            'name' => 'test123',
        ];

        $I->sendPost('/product/create', $data);

        $I->seeResponseIsJson();
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(HttpCode::OK);
        $I->seeResponseContainsJson([]);
    }
}
```

Examples of method calls of `ReadModel` object. Most of the code is cut off, I leaved only relevant parts of code.

```php
class JwtDecodedListener
{
    private ReadModel $readModel;

    public function __construct(
        ReadModel $readModel
    ) {
        $this->readModel = $readModel;
    }

    public function onJWTDecoded(JWTDecodedEvent $event)
    {
        // some code
        $client = new Client("mongodb://{$mongoDbUser}:{$mongoDbPass}@{$this->mongoHost}/{$mongoDb}");
        $this->readModel->setDatabase($client->selectDatabase($mongoDbUser));
    }
}
```

```php
class ProductProjection
{
    private ReadModel $readModel;

    public function __construct(
        ReadModel $readModel
    ) {
        $this->readModel = $readModel;
    }

    public function whenProductWasCreated(Product $product): void
    {
        // $collectionName is from a factory
        $collection = $this->readModel->getCollection($collectionName);
    }
}
```

Edit: As suggested in the comments I added `dump()` call in the constructor of `ReadModel` class and my conclusion is the same. Post request executed from postman - one constructor cal. The same request executed by Codeception - 2 constructor calls. Still have no idea what's the reason.

Comment: My first gut reaction is that Codeception can't fully understand your dep tree, even though Symfony can and it is set to "use Symfony". For instance, maybe there is a factory somewhere with a method takes a variable parameter that _could_ change which causes a second ReadModel. Regardless, I'd put some `dump` and/or `debug_print_backtrace` into the constructor to see what is invoking it to hopefully get you a bigger picture.

Comment: Can you explain where each method is called? Are both called when you send your POST-request to /product/create or are there multiple requests? What could cause this, is a reset of the container. For instance, [Symfony's KernelTestCase](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.x/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php#L155-L167) does this on tearDown and when booting a kernel.

Comment: @dbrumann both calls are made during the same POST call. First (setDatabase) is in a JwtDecodedListener (lexik JWT bundle) - it sets correct database based on user's request and second one (getCollection) is called in other services when there is a need to update something.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks for a suggestion. Checking

Comment: @dbrumann I added call examples to the question

Comment: Any success with this? I receive two instances of EventDispatcher in tests. And single instance if app is run from terminal, even in "test" env

Comment: @KarolDabrowski, how do you configure DI container before running tests? Are you using the Codeception Symfony plugin? If yes, could you share it's configuration, please?

Comment: I would suggest you use services.yaml and set `shared: true`

Answer (score 0):

Codeception re-creates the container before each test case runs. Persistence services are saved and passed to a new container without recreation. Use x-debug to see points of your service initialization.

I had the same issue with the entity manager. I've found that entity manager is shared between the test and controller, but some listeners were recreated twice. It happened because the kernel copies the persistence entity manager to the new container as an entire object without passing dependencies to the container. So my em used one listener object, and the rest of the code created a new lister and used it. I removed the direct injection of the listener of my code; I got the listener directly from the entity manager, and this fixed my issue.